# Spring Data JPA transient field returns wrong value

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have two models: `Deck` and `Word` with a one-to-many relationship. The `Deck` model has a transient field `showWordsToRevise`. I am trying to initialize that field with the amount of words in `List<Words>` with a `statusRepeating == true` field.

```
public class Deck {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "deck_id")
    private Long id;

    @Transient
    private Boolean showWordsToRevise;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deck", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Word> words;

    public Boolean getShowWordsToRevise() {
        System.out.println(this.words.stream().map(w -> w.getStatusRepeating()).count() + "  words to revise" + java.time.LocalDateTime.now().toString());
        return this.words.stream().map(w -> w.getStatusRepeating()).count() > 0;
    }

    public void setShowWordsToRevise(Boolean showWordsToRevise) {
        this.showWordsToRevise = showWordsToRevise;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Word {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "word_id")
    private Long id;
    private LocalDate last_checked;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private WordGroup wordGroup = WordGroup.newUnseen;
    @Transient
    private Boolean statusRepeating = false;
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name="deck_id",referencedColumnName="deck_id")
    private Deck deck;
    

    public Boolean getStatusRepeating() {
        if (this.wordGroup == WordGroup.first && Period.between(this.last_checked,LocalDate.now()).getDays() > 1) return true;
        if (this.wordGroup == WordGroup.second && Period.between(this.last_checked,LocalDate.now()).getDays() > 2) return true;
        return this.wordGroup == WordGroup.third && Period.between(this.last_checked, LocalDate.now()).getDays() > 7;
    }
    public void setStatusRepeating(Boolean statusRepeating) {
        this.statusRepeating = statusRepeating;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when there are no words in `List<Words>`  with `statusRepeating == true` the `showWordsToRevise` in `Word` still returns true.

[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01SCe.png)

Hibernate logs twice for the same request, first prints the wrong number, then prints the right number. **upd** it shows 0 at second print because there is no words in `List<Words>`

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        words0_.deck_id as deck_id8_3_0_,
        words0_.word_id as word_id1_3_0_,
        words0_.word_id as word_id1_3_1_,
        words0_.body as body2_3_1_,
        words0_.deck_id as deck_id8_3_1_,
        words0_.definition as definiti3_3_1_,
        words0_.example as example4_3_1_,
        words0_.last_checked as last_che5_3_1_,
        words0_.transcription as transcri6_3_1_,
        words0_.word_group as word_gro7_3_1_ 
    from
        word words0_ 
    where
        words0_.deck_id=?
1  words to revise2021-10-07T10:28:30.059128400
Hibernate: 
    select
        words0_.deck_id as deck_id8_3_0_,
        words0_.word_id as word_id1_3_0_,
        words0_.word_id as word_id1_3_1_,
        words0_.body as body2_3_1_,
        words0_.deck_id as deck_id8_3_1_,
        words0_.definition as definiti3_3_1_,
        words0_.example as example4_3_1_,
        words0_.last_checked as last_che5_3_1_,
        words0_.transcription as transcri6_3_1_,
        words0_.word_group as word_gro7_3_1_ 
    from
        word words0_ 
    where
        words0_.deck_id=?
0  words to revise2021-10-07T10:28:30.060126900
```

Comment: The field is never updated (and is transient) so why should it show anything else than what has been set through the setter. Basically with this getter/setter pair the field is pretty much useless. This applies to both your `statusRepeating` as well as the `statusRepeating` fields, those are pretty much useless with the current getters.

Comment: How can I update the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `Deck` class and change `getShowWordsToRevise()` method so that you count the words that have `statusRepeating == true`:

```java
public class Deck {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "deck_id")
    private Long id;

    @Transient
    private Boolean showWordsToRevise;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deck", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Word> words;

    public Boolean getShowWordsToRevise() {
        long wordsToReviseCount = this.words.stream().filter(WordLadder::getStatusRepeating).count();
        System.out.println(wordsToReviseCount + " words to revise " + java.time.LocalDateTime.now());
        return wordsToReviseCount > 0;
    }

    public void setShowWordsToRevise(Boolean showWordsToRevise) {
        this.showWordsToRevise = showWordsToRevise;
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like I confused `map` with `filter`. Thanks!